# Object reference not set to an instance of an object [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, ctype

```
 Public Class Form1
    Private Function AllEnabled(ByVal b As Boolean) As Boolean
        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            Dim c As CheckBox = CType(Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i.ToString), CheckBox)
            c.Enabled = b
        Next
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call AllEnabled(False)
     End Sub
    End Class
```

getting error with highlight in `b` at `c.Enabled = b`
(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

but when i use `checkbox1.enabled = b` instead of `c.enabled = b` works fine.

so as i see the wrong not with `b` right ?

& how can i fix this ?

Comment: I'm guessing this falls over when i = 0 ? Do you have a CheckBox0 on your form - again I'm guessing not. Have a look at the line <br> Dim c As CheckBox = CType(Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i.ToString), CheckBox) ... c is probably Nothing

Comment: Just tried debugging it for you and it fails for me on the Dim c as Checkbox line... can you post the asp code for your web form too?

Comment: don't have checkbox0 but i tried with [for loop] 1 To 2 & same result

Comment: @markp3rry this is the whole code

Comment: I mean the code from your web page - the html markup that has your controls on.

Comment: don't have web-page this is simple visual basic application

Comment: @Zaid - So you have a CheckBox2 on your form right?

Comment: `CheckBox1` & `CheckBox2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible reasons. Your for-loop creates this control names:

1. "CheckBox0"
2. "CheckBox1"
3. "CheckBox2"

Maybe you want 1-3 or 0-1 instead.

Maybe you want to find your checkbox recursively, then you can use `Find`:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 2
    Dim ctrl = Me.Controls.Find("CheckBox" & i.ToString, True)
    If ctrl.Length <> 0 Then
        ctrl(0).Enabled = b 'Find returns an aray' 
    End If
Next
```

Side-note: 2013 i would not use this VB6 style anymore:

```
Call AllEnabled(False)
```

but just

```
AllEnabled(False)
```

Comment: Works ! , Thank You , But could u explain what does `ctrl(0)` mean ? why the zero

Comment: @Zaid: I've commented it in my code snippet, `ControlCollection.Find` returns an array of controls. It is empty(`Length=0`) when no control was found with a given name as key. Since i assume that there is just one CheckBox with that name i've just taken the first. `ctrl(0)` gives me the first control in the control-array since arrays are zero based in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
  If TypeOf ctl Is CheckBox Then
   ctl.Enabled = b
  End If
Next
```

Comment: ops, it works the reason is the checkboxes was in group box 
thank u ! ^